# Signing data using X509certificate not working

Tags: asp.net, certificate, digital-signature, x509

I am working on real estate application using dotnet where we are transferring transactions to bank. For security purpose we ar using digital signatures to send transactions to bank. I have installed x509 certificate on server for creating digital signature using private key (.pfx). I have shared my public key, modulus & exponents with bank but they are not able to verify my digital signatures.They are saying our key i not valid. X509 certificate that i have installed is selfhosted is that creating problem. Please help.